# Preview Mode of Live Wallpaper Hangs?

Tags: android, preview, live-wallpaper

I made a 3D Wallpaper.There are four themes.I set one Theme as Wallpaper(Using the screen with "Settings" and "Set Wallpaper"). When i switch to another Theme, Preview Mode Hangs down.Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I suffered the same problem before.

Can you see EGL_BAD_SURFACE in your log?
In my case, calling egl.eglMakeCurrent before rendering fixes the problem.

Additionally, both of the home screen and the LWP preview tries creating your OpenGL instance separately; so, you should track creating and terminating OpenGL instances to prevent creating multiple instances.

I hope this helps you:)